# MySQL my.cnf file? - MySQL Server 5.1

Tags: mysql

I have MySQL Server 5.1 installed on my computer (complete), and I can't seem to find the my.cnf file. I don't even have the etc directory. And I've also done a complete search for it but no results... Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: Please tag the question to indicate which OS you're running, as it affects the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using windows?

/etc is a *nix configuration directory so I am guessing you are running MySql in Windows.

See [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/windows-create-option-file.html) regarding the my.cnf file on windows.

Answer (score 0):

on unix:

```
locate my.cnf
```